# Notification bar doesn't show up when the original question is deleted or migrated while typing an answer

Tags: bug, status-norepro, notifications

It occurred twice to me last month. The last time I recall that it worked was more than two months ago.

I however do see that the page body shifts a bit to the bottom to create room for the bar, but the bar itself doesn't show up at all. Too bad that I didn't check for any JS/CSS errors. I also don't have the playground environment to try to reproduce this (I don't think that we're allowed to abuse Meta for this).

Using Firefox 3.6.3 on Windows XP.

---

**Update**: this has occurred once again recently. This time the question got migrated while I was busy improving the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844708/what-is-easiest-way-to-setup-a-localhost-in-your-computer). I took a [screenshot](http://tweakers.net/ext/f/nqFqQgG9fFoMm7igf6xpyCwT/full.png) (note the blank space in top), but there were no JS/CSS errors.

The "new answer has been posted" notification has by the way always worked flawlessly. I just tested it directly thereafter without changing/restarting the webbrowser and here's a [sceenshot](http://tweakers.net/ext/f/LNtbv5YDVaoaV08XKdKXc2Ef/full.png) as evidence.

---

**Update 2**: just wanted to inform that it [works](http://tweakers.net/ext/f/RR2EomlprLePqI3Z2PLrpDca/full.png) again! Last time I recall it didn't show anything in the room for the bar was two days ago. Was something changed with regard to this in the meanwhile?

Comment: To anyone: I would however love to see if I am not the only who encounters this problem. If you experience the same problem, please leave a comment.

Comment: I just spent an hour typing out a response to SO and the question was deleted in Chrome, no notification bar showed up, only a 'Page Not Found' upon refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug or at least a (perhaps unawarely) related bug has been fixed somewhere in the week before 13 august 2010.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce this behavior on Firefox 3.6.3 or IE8.

The ajax callback that checks a question's status happens once every 45 seconds - perhaps you were unlucky in your answer submission timing and a callback didn't get a chance to fire.

We'll discuss lowering the callback interval a bit so you can get updated status information faster.

Comment: Actually, I didn't submit the answer at all, I was still busy typing it until I noticed a page shift. I then opened the question in a new tab and I saw that it was deleted. Anyway, thanks for the effort and I'll keep an eye if this would occur again :)

Comment: @BalusC - no problem!  Let us know if you can get a consistent repro or any javascript errors.

Comment: It happened once again, but I didn't get any JS/CSS errors.